# Magento Top menu

Tags: html, magento

I am developing a magento site and confused in changing magento top menu.

The menu where it says " Language, Currency, About U,s Our Blog, Customer Servic,e Privacy Policy , Contact Us, Welcome"

[image]

I have't found any setting to change header menu. Anyone can help?

Comment: This part is not configurable from the admin, it requires a developer to [adjust the theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/%7Bsite_url%7Ddesign_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts).  Are you asking for programming help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Magento's RWD Theme, you will find it in layouts/page.xml under section

```
  <default translate="label" module="page">
```

The corresponding template files you can find under:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you use the template hinting option in the developer tools found in your admin panel. It's very handy for figuring out which files need to be changed in order to modify different structural blocks. This is often relied upon by Magento developers because the file-structure/architecture of Magento can be really complex.

If the template hinting option isn't available to you, you can download a free plugin from the Magento Connect plugin repository that accomplishes the same thing.